# Can't enter keystore second password when exporting Android app in eclipse

Tags: android, keystore

I'm running into a strange error - I'm exporting an Android application in Eclipse using a keystore I had previously created and used. Now when I try to export a different application using the existing keystore, I'm unable to enter the second password. Any idea why?

Comment: Is there a message in the top corner that says "This Keystore has been corrupted or tampered with"?

Comment: Thanks for asking this and your follow-up comment below. That is what "unstuck" me. I thought the confirm field would become enabled if I typed in the password correctly. Spread the word..

Comment: Glad to help, Libby. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean, the key password (as opposed to the keystore)? Then you've probably mistyped the keystore password.

If you mean that the second password box on the keystore password screen is greyed out, that's by design. The same screen is used to create a new keystore with a password and open an existing one (providing a password). You only need two copies in password creation scenario.

Comment: Thanks. It was the second condition I had. I should've figured that out. The next screen wanted an alias, which kind of threw me off track. Alias? Why? Anyway, I got through it.